# Can functions with interfaces be passed as parameters?

Tags: function, go, interface

I know that functions can be passed as parameters. But I would like to use a function taking a type implementing an interface as input to a function. Is this still possible?

I have tried the following and it gives `cannot use myfn1 (type func(int)) as type fn in argument to test` as error.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type intf interface{}

type fn func(i intf)

func myfn1(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("\ni is %v", i)
}
func myfn2(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("\ni is %v", i)
}
func test(f fn, val int) {
    f(val)
}
func main() {

    test(fn(myfn1), 123)
    test(myfn2, 321)
}
```

You can try it at: https://play.golang.org/p/Al7USxzmYST

Changing `type fn func(i intf)` to `type fn func(i int)` of course solves the issue. But I don't understand whether it can be made to work with the interface.

Comment: It can absolutely pass a function that takes interface-typed arguments; there's nothing special about them. But *because there's nothing special about them*, you can only pass them to a function that takes a function of that type.

Comment: Put another way, the signature of the function you pass *must match exactly* the signature of the argument you're passing it to.

Comment: test needs a function that accepts any intf and you're trying to give it a function that takes only int. This doesn't work in *any* language, not just in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any type of function as an argument. However, when you pass a function as an argument, the function signature has to match. So you cannot pass a function taking an interface in place of a function that takes an int.

Passing an interface value to a function is different than passing an int. When you call a function with an int value, it simply passes that value. But when you pass a int value to a function getting interface{}, it has to create an interface value containing the type of the value and the value itself, and pass that.